# IDLE text editor/Python2.7/Mac OS X/ "URLError: <urlopen error no host given>"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I put in this script to IDLE 2.7.14

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'http:www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
```

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
", line 1126, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
>>>
```

Backstory: I installed and uninstalled BeautifulSoup, Pycharm, and downloaded Python 2x earlier...

Comment: Should not the URL be: `http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND`?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with which text editor you use.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is incorrectly formed. It should be:

```
quote_page = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'
```